# Why does Meteor's aldeed/meteor-tabular package get stuck processing and never render a result?

Tags: node.js, meteor, aldeedmeteor-tabular

About 1 in 5 times when I click on a column header to sort, the sort doesn't actually happen and the "processing" indicator text doesn't go away.

I have to sort again to make the message disappear.

Please advise me toward a solution.

https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular/issues/321

Comment: Could [PR #318](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular/pull/318) be of any help for your case?

Answer (score 0):

I already fix this, there should be some issue related to this in `meteor-admin` package. It's just a visual problem, you can solve this simply not displaying the indicator.

I have this rule in my css and it should work (now I can't test, if this is the exact rule, sorry):

```
div.dataTables_wrapper div.dataTables_processing {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's not just that the indicator shows.  The sort never happens ( data is not refreshed).

Comment: Any chance we could pull this in?  https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular/pull/318

Answer (score 0):

As followed up on the GitHub repo [issue #321](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular/issues/321), it seems this bug can be corrected by [PR #318](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular/pull/318).

Unfortunately, it looks like the repo maintainers are not very active on it (surely working hard to pay their bills :-) ), so for the meantime you could simply use [gaiazov's fork](https://github.com/gaiazov/meteor-tabular) (from which PR #318 originates) to have a working version of the package.

In order to do that:

1. Create a folder named `packages` at the root of your Meteor project, if it does not already exist.
2. Create a subfolder (whatever its name) into that `packages` folder.
3. Copy the content of the package into that subfolder.
4. Remove then re-add `aldeed:tabular` package. When re-added, Meteor will first look into your local packages in the `packages` folder.

There is also another way using a global packages folder, but you would need to manage code versioning (git…) separately. The description for this method can be easily found on the Internet.

See also the reference page: [Meteor Guide > Build > Writing Atmosphere Packages > Overriding packages with a local version](https://guide.meteor.com/writing-atmosphere-packages.html#overriding-atmosphere-packages)