# how to use a fork of a meteor package when the original package is a dependency

Tags: javascript, git, meteor, meteor-autoform

**Context**

I'm using the aldeed:autoform package and found a couple bugs & filed PR for it(https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform).

Aldeed being the only maintainer of a lot of popular packages ends up being the bottleneck for merging PR & following up with issues.
My solution was to fork his project & published my fork on atmosphere.

Naively, i just removed his package `meteor remove aldeed:autoform` and tried to add mine: `meteor add metakungfu:autoform`

When i load my app, i get the following error:
[image]

`Package['aldeed:autoform']` returns the expected object, even though i removed the package.

For sake of completeness, i do use a bunch of other packages that depends on aldeed:autoform and my guess is that this is the reason why aldeed:autoform package is still present.

**Questions:**

- What's the right way to use a fork of a package, when that package is dependency of other packages?
- Is this the right way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've end up using [mgp](https://github.com/DispatchMe/mgp) to manage the packages.
In order to solve my problem, i had to do two things:

First, add a `git-packages.json` in the root of your project that looks like this:

```
➜ cat git-packages.json
{
  "aldeed:autoform": {
    "git": "git@github.com:gregory/meteor-autoform.git",
    "branch": "dev"
  }
}
```

This will work locally, but if you deploy to heroku, the buildpack will need to install mgp & install the dependencies.

I just [opened a PR to fix this](https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse/pull/141)

Comment: Any clean solutions for getting your forked version of a package to work with `meteor build` command? I'm deploying to AWS Beanstalk and first build a raw `Node` version of the app

Answer (score 0):

Fork all the dependencies and make them point to your fork.

Comment: that would probably work, but would be really sad to do :) - that mean you'll have to maintain all those forks anytime there is an update...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of publishing your own version of `aldeed:autoform` onto Atmosphere, you should rather use it as a local package, keeping its name intact. Meteor will look first for your local packages, before trying to fetch from Atmosphere.

That way, all your other packages that depend on it will use your local version.

To do that, see: [Why does Meteor's aldeed/meteor-tabular package get stuck processing and never render a result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37934553/why-does-meteors-aldeed-meteor-tabular-package-get-stuck-processing-and-never-r/38459817#38459817)

Reference: [Meteor Guide > Build > Writing Atmosphere Packages > Overriding packages with a local version](https://guide.meteor.com/writing-atmosphere-packages.html#overriding-atmosphere-packages)

Comment: Isn't it sad to have to copy/past a bunch of files into your project and loosing  the versioning? Isn't there a way i could use a package management solution where i could have autoform to point to my fork instead? that would be ideal... - At least, meteorite had an option to point to a fork: https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite#usage

Comment: I am sure you have plenty options, from git submodules to npm with symlinks… The only requirement is to get in the end your own version in `/packages` with the same name as the original package.